# Prove that lim of x/(x+1) = 1 as x approaches infinity

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I want to prove that $$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{x}{x+1}=1$$

I know that I need to show that:
$$\left|\frac{1}{x+1}\right| \lt \epsilon$$
But I'm not sure how to manipulate it.
Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The tag (epsilon-delta) suggests you want an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof. Only of the answers so far does that and only one other comes reasonably close to doing this. My question to you: are you after an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof?

Answer (score 7):

Rearrange it as follows:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{x}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{x}+1}$$
Can you see why the limit is $1?$

Answer (score 4):

If $x>-1$, then $x+1>0$, so you can drop the absolute values
$$
\frac{1}{x+1}<\varepsilon.
$$
Note that this is equivalent to 
$$
x+1>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}.
$$

Comment: how did you determine that x > -1 ?

Comment: @Nicole Since $x$ is approaching infinity, you are considering $x$ as it gets bigger and bigger.  So, you can assume that $x>-1$.

Comment: oh i see okay thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated over $\varepsilon - \delta $ ?
I suggest $ \frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{1}{1+1/x} $, thus

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+1/x} = 1 $ since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac1x = 0$

Answer (score 0):

We have: $0 < \left|\dfrac{x}{x+1} - 1\right| = \dfrac{1}{|x+1|} < \dfrac{1}{|x|} = \dfrac{1}{x}$. Use squeeze lemma to get $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\dfrac{x}{x+1} -1\right) =0 \Rightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{x}{x+1} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a much simpler approach is to write $x$ as $x + 1 - 1$ and then you get $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \frac{x + 1 - 1}{x + 1} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\left ( 1 - \frac{1}{x+1}  \right )$

p.s. this kinda "trick" can be useful when integrating too ;)